# Database performance concerns - repeated data

Tags: database, performance

I have some database performance concerns (not yet a real issue but I  would like to make sure everything is good enough).

I have around 10 tables that are connected. There is one main object/table that is 'mother' of all and contains the userID (these records are user specific). So, if I want to get any record from any table for specific user I would have to do lets say 5+ joins.

I decided to avoid complications with joins so I added this userID to all tables. Now if I want to get records from a specific table for specific user I wont need any joins.

Would this cause any issues and is it bad practice is my question.

Microsoft technologies used for both application and database.

Comment: [DATABASE NORMALIZATION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little hard to say without understanding the structure of your joins.  I take it from your question that you have a hierarchy of tables like:
Customers -> Invoices -> Orders -> OrderItems, (where -> = 1 to many) and the question is it problematic to include sy, customer ID in the OrderItems table because without it, to determine customerID for a particular order item you'd have to traverse back up the chain to get Order, then Invoice in order to get customer ID (give that CustomerID is the join column between Customers and Invoices.)

The answer is probably "it depends".  If you are purist you would probably avoid that, but if you often find you have an OrderItem record, but the you don't thave the invoiceID to hand. and you need to find say "customer address" from the customer table, then maybe its worth it.

things to think about is whether or not the relationships are volatile or not, e.g. whether or not say, an an invoice can be transferred from one customer to another, or an order can be transferred from one invoice to another.  If that were the case, then you would have ot make sure to remember to change not only the customerID in Invoices, but also the customerID on all of the orders on that invoice, and all of the orderitems in each order.  If you take the fully normalized approach,  you only have 1 update to make.  If not, you could have many writes to many different tables depending on how deep you go into the hierarchy and how many records are on the many side in your db.  If you have sprinkled customerIDs sprinkled liberally all over the hierarchy, that could be a lot of writes, and keeping everything in synch could be a pain in the neck.

If the folks who are writing code against your db don't really understand exactly what you've done, it could turn inot a bloody mess and I think that's why people would tend to avoid it.

I would say to be practical about it.  How often do you find you need to traverse the hierarchy to do something you want to do, and whether or not the the foreign key you are replicating is ever likely to change.

Comment: You understood my question and the type of hierarchy correct. Thank you for the answer, this is what I looked for!